# Create a DataGridView with a Caption (Embed in GroupBox)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb6-migration

I have a DataGridView and I want to put it into a GroupBox. In VB6 it looked like this:

[image: MsFlexGrid with Caption in VB6]

So it is just a MsFlexGrid wrapped by a GroupBox. I've absolutely no idea, how to implement that in VB.NET.

I'd let it inherit from DataGridView, so it is a Control, and it has every Property of the DataGridView by default.

```
Public Class CaptionedDataGridView
    Inherits DataGridView
```

There would also have to be a GroupBox:

```
Private xGroupBox as GroupBox
```

The text property would be overrided by the text of the group box as well as some size and placement properties (Top, Left, Width, Height)

```
Public Overrides Property Text As String
  Get
    Return xGroupBox.Text
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As Integer)
    xGroupBox.Text = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Finally, if I'd create a new CaptionedDataGridView somewhere it should draw itself with the GroupBox sorrounded. How do I get from where I am right now to where I want to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do that the other way around.  Inherit from the GroupBox and add the DataGridView to it.

Simple example:

```
Public Class MyGrid
  Inherits GroupBox

  Private _Grid As DataGridView

  Public Sub New()
    _Grid = New DataGridView()
    _Grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(_Grid)
  End Sub

  ReadOnly Property Grid As DataGridView
    Get
      Return _Grid
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

Of course, you don't have to do this as a custom control.  You can just put a GroupBox on your form and add the DataGridView to it with that same DockStyle.Fill property.

Comment: I thought about this, too. I thought it would be nicer to have the inheritance from DataGridView rahter than GroupBox, as this would be more logical. As I use so many propertys from DataGridView and just the Text, Left, Top, Width, Height Property of the TextBox. Of course, this is a valid solution for my problem.